# Resizing a matrix

Tags: arrays, memory-management, julia

I am trying to come up with a performant way of resizing a matrix in Julia. This matrix is just used as an internal cache for Jacobians inside of some methods, and so its values do not need to be preserved in any order (they will be immediately overwritten). I was thinking about generating a vector directly and working with the matrix being the reshape'd view of that vector. However, Julia then blocks me from `resize!`ing the vector:

```
Jvec = zeros(9)
J = reshape(Jvec,3,3))
resize!(Jvec,16)


cannot resize array with shared data
 in resize!(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Int64) at ./array.jl:512
 in include_string(::String, ::String) at ./loading.jl:441
 in eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:234
 in (::Atom.##67#70)() at /home/crackauc/.julia/v0.5/Atom/src/eval.jl:40
 in withpath(::Atom.##67#70, ::Void) at /home/crackauc/.julia/v0.5/CodeTools/src/utils.jl:30
 in withpath(::Function, ::Void) at /home/crackauc/.julia/v0.5/Atom/src/eval.jl:46
 in macro expansion at /home/crackauc/.julia/v0.5/Atom/src/eval.jl:109 [inlined]
 in (::Atom.##66#69)() at ./task.jl:60
```

and also won't let me `resize!` the vector with the view gone (with the hope of just creating a new view afterwards):

```
J = 0
resize!(Jvec,16)

cannot resize array with shared data
 in resize!(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Int64) at ./array.jl:512
 in include_string(::String, ::String) at ./loading.jl:441
 in eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:234
 in (::Atom.##67#70)() at /home/crackauc/.julia/v0.5/Atom/src/eval.jl:40
 in withpath(::Atom.##67#70, ::Void) at /home/crackauc/.julia/v0.5/CodeTools/src/utils.jl:30
 in withpath(::Function, ::Void) at /home/crackauc/.julia/v0.5/Atom/src/eval.jl:46
 in macro expansion at /home/crackauc/.julia/v0.5/Atom/src/eval.jl:109 [inlined]
 in (::Atom.##66#69)() at ./task.jl:60
```

Any insight into how to accomplish this without fully re-allocating the matrix each time is helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you just allocate a new matrix? What will resizing instead gain you?

Comment: If I resize to a smaller matrix, I shouldn't need to re-allocate. If I resize up, it should be amortized like vectors. That should make it much faster if I do it repeatedly.

Comment: At little bit more detail: it gets loaded up via `ForwardDiff.jacobian!`, and then is used for a \ operation. That's it. I can see [from this page of the source](https://github.com/JuliaDiff/ForwardDiff.jl/blob/master/src/jacobian.jl) that to make it efficient it just needs to index well, I am not sure about making it work well with \ operations though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're treading on somewhat dangerous territory (that warning is there for a reason), but if instead of calling `reshape(Jvec, 3, 3)` you do

```
J = Base.ReshapedArray(Jvec,(3,3), ())
```

then it may work as you are hoping.

Comment: Looks like it works. "You're treading on somewhat dangerous territory". Danger sounds interesting.

Answer (score 4):

```
julia> J = rand(3,3);

julia> Jvec = vec(J);

julia> resize!(Jvec, 4*4);

julia> J = reshape(Jvec, (4,4));

julia> Jvec = vec(J);

julia> resize!(Jvec, 5*5);

julia> J = reshape(Jvec, (5,5))
```

etc works.

Comment: If, before generating the new `J`, you change a value in `Jvec`, you'll see that it created a new vector. It looks like it didn't because it copies the values, but the link between `J` and `Jvec` is broken, presumably to stop the issue from my solution.